# select columns with value NA

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sql-server-2012, ssms

How to select columns in a table that only contain a specific value for all the rows? I am trying to find these columns to do an update on those values with a `NULL` value. In my columns I have varied range of values including NA

I am using `SQL Server 2012`.

I've tried doing: thsi only gives me column names. Can i add to this condition for columns with value 'NA'?

```
SELECT  COLUMN_NAME AS NAMES,COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'ABC'
```

I am a beginner in `SQL`. Trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: honestly?  I'd build a quick console app in your preferred language to do this

Comment: @Shyam  can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: Can i know why there is -1 above?

Comment: YOU WANT TO REPLACE COLUMNS WITH NULLS TO 'NA'?

Comment: @ Dudi replace columns with value NA as NULL. A lot of these are datatype integer columns.

Answer (score 1):

If min of column equals to max then that column contains same values:

```
Select 
    case when min(col1) = max(col1) then 1 else 0 end as Col1IsSame,
    case when min(col2) = max(col2) then 1 else 0 end as Col2IsSame,
    ...
from Table
```

With dynamic query:

```
declare @s nvarchar(max) = 'select '

select  @s = @s + 'case when min(' + COLUMN_NAME + ') = max(' + 
        COLUMN_NAME + ') then 1 else 0 end as ' + COLUMN_NAME + ','
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table'

Set @s = substring(@s, 1, len(@s)  - 1) + ' from Table'

exec(@s)
```

Comment: @ Giorgi, Thank you. Is there a way I can do it without passing every column name? Also..in my columns I have varied range of values including NA

Comment: @ giorgi That's a brilliant solution! I am looking forward to learning Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS QUERY

```
DECLARE @SQLQUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @tableName varchar(50)
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(50)
Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar(2000) 
Set @ParamDefinition =      '@OIM VARCHAR(20)'
SELECT   NAME    
FROM sys.objects  
WHERE [object_id]=@OIM 

 set  @tableName= (SELECT   NAME    
FROM sys.objects  
WHERE [object_id]=@OIM)

SET @NAME=(SELECT C.NAME
FROM  sys.columns c 
  JOIN 
  sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id 

WHERE  c.name  in (select distinct name
                    from sys.columns           
                    where  object_id=@OIM))

SET @SQLQUERY = ''

SELECT @SQLQUERY = @SQLQUERY + 'UPDATE ' + @tableName + ' SET ' + @NAME + ' = NULL WHERE ' + @NAME + ' = NA ; '  

    PRINT @SQLQUERY
                    Execute sp_Executesql     @SQLQUERY ,  @ParamDefinition, @OIM
end
```